# android.graphics.Bitmap.sameAs in android O not return true when compare 2 bitmaps same config, dimensions, pixel data

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap

I create the clone bitmap from original bitmap in native.
And try to compare 2 bitmap in java layer by api [android.graphics.Bitmap.sameAs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)), it return **false** in **Android O**, but return **true** in other Android version. 
Besides, I also try compare config, dimensions, pixel data by android bitmap APIs in android O, such as:

```
private boolean compareBitmap(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)
{
    // Different types of image
    if (bitmap1.getConfig() != bitmap2.getConfig())
        return false;

    // Different sizes
    if (bitmap1.getWidth() != bitmap2.getWidth())
        return false;

    if (bitmap1.getHeight() != bitmap2.getHeight())
        return false;

    int w = bitmap1.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap1.getHeight();

    int[] argbA = new int[w * h];
    int[] argbB = new int[w * h];

    bitmap1.getPixels(argbA, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    bitmap2.getPixels(argbB, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

    // Alpha channel special check
    if (bitmap1.getConfig() == Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
    {
        final int length = w * h;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if ((argbA[i] & 0xFF000000) != (argbB[i] & 0xFF000000))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return Arrays.equals(argbA, argbB);
}
```

The method compareBitmap() also return true in android O. 
So, I have no idea why the [android.graphics.Bitmap.sameAs()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#sameAs(android.graphics.Bitmap)) return false in this case, when 2 bitmap have same config, dimensions, pixel data?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got bitmaps from the same drawable resource this can help you. 
I had a same issue and for me it was resolved by setting tint to drawable (which I was converted to Bitmap for comparison purposes).

Answer (score 1):

**I had to set Tint to make them similar:**

```
private fun getBitmap(drawable: Drawable): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.intrinsicWidth,
            drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    drawable.setTint(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    drawable.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}



private fun compareBitMap(bitmap: Bitmap, otherBitmap: Bitmap): Boolean {
    val bitMapAreSame = bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap) &&
            (bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.width == otherBitmap.width &&
                    bitmap.height == otherBitmap.height &&
                    bitmap.byteCount == otherBitmap.byteCount &&
                    bitmap.density == otherBitmap.density)
    bitmap.recycle()
    otherBitmap.recycle()
    return bitMapAreSame
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Double-check if the bitmap passed is not null. If it's null, it will return `false`. Otherwise, I can't see why is returning it

Comment: I really check bitmap is not null before using compareBitmap(). As you know, bitmap.sameAs() is return FALSE in Android O but return TRUE in older Android versions